# Spring REST return byte[] like field in response

Tags: arrays, json, spring, spring-restcontroller

I have a class `ProductItem`

```
@Data
public class ProductItem {
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private byte[] image;
}
```

And Spring rest method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
private ResponseEntity<ProductItem> findProduct() {
    ProductItem i= service.getProductItem()
    return ResponseEntity.ok(i);
}
```

How can I correctly return `byte[]` in  this class?

Comment: do you want to return the byte only or the whole class?

Comment: what is issue, it should work, only thing i think is missing is produces in mapping. Your mapping should be @GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [base64 encode](http://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode) the byte[] to a String in you ProductItem's field

Or

You can add HttpServletReponse to your method and [write the byte[] in the response's OutputStream](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-image-media-data). In this case no need to return ResponseEntity.